# Calculating the probability of k changeovers when flipping a coin when P(H) = 0.2

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471300/calculating-the-probability-of-k-changeovers-when-flipping-a-coin), but I'm not sure how to modify it for unequal P(H) and P(T).

My guess:
$$P(C_k) = {n-1\choose k} (0.2)^{k-1}(0.8)^{n-k-1}$$

How does that look?

Comment: It does not give the right answer when $n=2$ and $k=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can I use indicator variables? Let I_i = 1 if there's a changeover, and 0 otherwise. P(I_i = 1) = 2*(0.2*0.8) = 0.32

Then P(k changeovers) = k*P(I_i = 1) = k*0.32 ??

Comment: I have not thought about it. You can certainly do it to find the **mean** number of changeovers.

Comment: One can get a recurrence, but as of now I do not see how to turn that into a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the side of the coin which was thrown first, and $Y$ be the other side of it. Then
$$
k_X=\left\lceil\frac{k+1}2\right\rceil,\quad k_Y=\left\lfloor\frac{k+1}2\right\rfloor\tag1
$$
are the numbers of the uninterrupted sequences of the coin sides $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Then the probability to have $k$ changeovers in $n$ throws is:
$$
\sum_{i=k_Y}^{n-k_Y}\left[\binom{i-1}{k_X-1}\binom{n-i-1}{k_Y-1}
+\binom{i-1}{k_Y-1}\binom{n-i-1}{k_X-1}\right]p^i(1-p)^{n-i},\tag2
$$
where the factor $\binom{i-1}{k_X-1}\binom{n-i-1}{k_Y-1}$ counts the number of ways to distribute $i$ $X$-coins and $(n-i)$ $Y$-coins between $k_X$ and $k_Y$ cells, respectively, provided that no cell is empty (see [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))). The sum in brackets accounts for two possibilities of the first throw.

The expression $(2)$ degenerates to
$$
\binom{n-1}k\frac1{2^{n-1}}
$$
for $p=\frac12$.